# Prevent UIPickerView from pushing views upwards

Tags: ios, swift

I have a picker as input view of a text field and everything works. The problem is, each time the text field is tapped and the picker appears on the bottom of the screen, it pushes the other views upwards - even though it's far form covering the text field. I know it's a desirable behavior for the soft keyboard, but in my case it's no good. Is it possible to make the picker appear without moving the other views upwards?

My code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    let chartTypePicker = UIPickerView()
    chartTypeTextField.inputView = chartTypePicker
    chartTypeTextField.text = "Line chart"
    chartTypePicker.center = view.center // doesn't work
    chartTypePicker.delegate = self
}
```

I also have the pickerView functions and everything else. Everything works perfectly, I just don't want it to move the other views. Thanks for any advice!

EDIT: I've uploaded pictures. Sorry for the bad quality and for having the content blacked out, I cannot share it publicly.

Before and after. The views are pushed to the top when the picker comes up from the bottom. They stay there even after the picker goes away. The text view which has the picker as input is in the red ellipse. So what I'd like to have is, that the views are not pushed upwards when the picker appears.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you using IQKeyboard or something like this?

Comment: Can you please add some screenshots of your view before the picker and after the picker. If you can upload a short video that would help more to understand your problem

Comment: I don't use anything special, just the standard picker and standard views (the charts are from the Charts library, displayed inside a container view and they are swapped with the picker).

Comment: I've uploaded some photos, hope they're useful. I cannot post a video unfortunately.

Comment: Please provide the code when keyboard is shown/hides